# How to set gravity of textview programatically with RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, baseadapter, gravity

I am developing an android app. I am populating ListView by inflating rows as follows:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context con;
    private LayoutInflater layoutinf;
    ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<String> items_ = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyListAdapter(ChatActivity context) {
        con = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return item_id.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

        //  holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
            holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);

        }
                    else if(item_flag.get(position).equals("0"))
                    {
                        holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

                    }


        //holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));
        holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));
        holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Layout file is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msg_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/phone_num"
    android:layout_below="@id/phone_num"
    android:text="SMS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/msg_body"
    android:text="time"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

How can i set TextView gravity right programatically using RelativeLayout in above Code???

Comment: Do you want the text in textView to have gravity right, or the layout of TextViews to have layout gravity right?

Comment: i want the have layout of TextViews to have gravity right .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set like this..

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: @NameSpace have you seen the xml file one textview is right side and another is left then how thew will flush??..that too if you want you can give align to another view with layoutparams

Comment: you're right in this case, viewed the xml, they were on separate lines, so aligning both parent right will have same effect.

Comment: Lets suppose i have nothing to do with TextView having id as @+id/time which is aligned right in XML.I am asking question about TextView msg_body which was aligned left in XML. i want to set it at right using my code , how can i do this???